# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while connecting with sys as sysdba

Tags: oracle10g, sys, sysdba

I installed Oracle database 10g as an administrator on a windows 10 machine, it worked fine, but when i try to connect sys as sysdba it gives me the error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I checked ***sqlnet.ora*** file and if  SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES is NTS and it is:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

I added the user to the ORA_DBA group and i checked with:

```
c:\Oracle>echo %username%
```

and

```
c:\Oracle>NET LOCALGROUP ORA_DBA
```

and the user is  in the group.

I don't know what else i should do, anything will be helpful.

Comment: I think you have better chance to solve your problem if you ask your question on [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) website.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to share what you exactly did? Please, copy/paste your command prompt session; something like this:

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pet Pro 15 22:13:41 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

or

```
C:\>sqlplus sys@xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pet Pro 15 22:18:59 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

A possible culprit: have you modified TNSNAMES.ORA file and added some databases in there? If so, try to specify database name (as I did in my second example).